# Complex Function Continuity

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I am trying to get this through my head about continuity of complex functions.

Say you have $f(z) = \dfrac{z^2}{|z|}$, and I want to show that the function is continuous everywhere on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$ and why. I know that if $z = x + yi$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, that
\begin{equation*}
f(z) = f(x + yi) = \dfrac{(x + yi)^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \dfrac{x^2 - y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} + i\dfrac{2xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
\end{equation*}
Then $u(x, y) = \dfrac{x^2 - y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ and $v(x, y) = \dfrac{2xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$.

Clearly, if $z = 0 + 0i$, then the function is not continuous (because we have a $\frac{0}{0}$ situation for both $u, v$). But otherwise, if $u(x, y) = \dfrac{x^2 - y^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$ and $v(x, y) = \dfrac{2xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$, it is continuous everywhere for any nonzero complex number because $u(x, y)$ is continuous anywhere nonzero and $v(x, y)$ is also continuous anywhere nonzero. Therefore, since $u(x, y)$ and $v(x, y)$ are continuous for any nonzero complex number, it follows that $f(z)$ is also continuous for any nonzero complex number.

I am not sure if my justification is correct. Maybe some advice or explanation would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your justification is correct. There is no need to mention the case of $0$, since the domain of $f$ is $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

But it's much simpler to simply say that $f$ is the quotient of two continuous functions ($z\mapsto z^2$ and $z\mapsto|z|$) and that therefore it is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

$$
\begin{align}
&z=re^{i\theta}\\
&z^2=r^2e^{i\cdot 2\theta}\\
&|z|=r\\
&f(z)=\frac{z^2}{|z|}=re^{i\cdot 2\theta}
\end{align}
$$

which is continuous everywhere.